# ID anchors are scrolling slightly too far

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

HTML for the section:

```
<br style="clear: both;" />

<hr />

<section id="work" class="box-sub">
    <h1 class="work">WORK</h1>        
    <div class="float-full">     
        <a href="fold.php"><img src="img/fold-tn2.png" class="thumbnail" /></a>
        <a href="ones-up.php"><img src="img/ou-tn2.png" class="thumbnail" /></a>  
        <img src="img/temp.png" class="thumbnail" />
        <img src="img/temp.png" class="thumbnail" />
        <img src="img/temp.png" class="thumbnail" />
        <img src="img/temp.png" class="thumbnail" />
    </div>
</section>
```

I'm only using the ID as an anchor, CSS for box-sub:

```
.box-sub {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

The anchor is scrolling too far before stopping. I want it to stop above the `h1` work, but it's scrolling over it even though it's linked to `#work`, see below:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#top"></a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#work"></a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#info"></a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
            event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
    });
</script>
```

I've displayed the section IDs as block in the CSS but it doesn't help.

```
#work { display: block; }
#info { display: block; }
#contact { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely the padding causing the issue. Try removing it to see if it corrects itself. If so, then use a div wrapper set to the width you want, and place the contents with the padding inside the div wrapper.